# upload files, create two new directorys and place the file there PHP

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

When a user submits the form they enter a ref number and can upload up to 3 documents.

When they submit, i want the document to be saved in the folder structure like so:

```
 docs/
     12345/1/file.jpg
     12345/2/file.jpg
             anotherfile.jpg

     27635/1/afile.png
             anotherfile.png
             thirdfile.jpg

     34827/1/onefile.jpg
```

Okay so you get the idea, when a user uploads a file, it makes a new folder inside docs/ with their reference number then makes another folder called 1/with the files. if the user then uploads again with the same reference it will create a folder inside their reference with the next number up containing their files.

**HTML:**

```
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="text" name="reference"/><br/>
        <input type="file" name="pictures[]" /><br/>
        <input type="file" name="pictures[]" /><br/>
        <input type="file" name="pictures[]" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />

    </form>
```

**PHP:**

```
     <?php


$target_dir = "docs/";
$ref = $_POST['reference'];

if(!file_exists($target_dir . $ref . '/')){
    mkdir($target_dir . $ref . "/1/");
    $count = 0;
}else{
    //count the amount of folders inside docs/$ref/
    $find_folders = glob($target_dir . $ref . "/*",GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    $count = count($find_folders);
    //create new folder inside $ref/ using count+1 to make the folder increase by 1
        $new_folder = $count +1;
        mkdir($target_dir . $ref . "/" . $new_folder . "/");        
}
//If count exists then the $target_file changes to the new folder
    if($count > 0){
        $target_file = $target_dir . $ref . $new_folder . "/";  
    }else{//else use first directory
        $target_file = $target_dir . $ref ."/1/";
    }




foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["name"] as $key => $Name) 
{
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_file . "$name");
}


?>
```

**When i try all i get is the error:**
Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\test\upload.php on line 8

arning: move_uploaded_file(docs/123/1/1.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\test\upload.php on line 32

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php2E4E.tmp' to 'docs/123/1/1.png' in C:\wamp\www\test\upload.php on line 32

Any ideas on this? i'm just scratching my head over this one

Comment: Make sure `$target_dir` DOES get you to the directory... Because looks like it doesn't.

Comment: Why doesnt it? i was sure it did?

Comment: 1. What's the path to this above PHP file?
2. Now what's the path to `docs`?

Comment: main directory is test, inside that is my index.php with the form, upload.php for the form submission and the docs/ folder

Comment: does the folder docs/123/1/ get created?

Comment: nope, nothing happens which is strange. I got it working for uplaoding files earlier and the docs did work. But now im trying to make it do if they use the same reference it makes a new folder there it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 problems.

First, as you are working with windows you need to use \ instead of / as directory separator. Best if you use the php constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.

Second, in order to recursively create directories, you need the third parameter of mkdir like so

```
mkdir($mypath,0777,TRUE);
```

Putting that together you should get something like this:

```
$target_dir = "docs".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$ref = $_POST['reference'];

if(!file_exists($target_dir . $ref . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)){
    mkdir($target_dir . $ref . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "1" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 0777, true);
    $count = 0;
}else{
    //count the amount of folders inside docs/$ref/
    $find_folders = glob($target_dir . $ref . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "*",GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    $count = count($find_folders);
    //create new folder inside $ref/ using count+1 to make the folder increase by 1
        $new_folder = $count +1;
        mkdir($target_dir . $ref . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $new_folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 0777, true);        
}
//If count exists then the $target_file changes to the new folder
    if($count > 0){
        $target_file = $target_dir . $ref . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $new_folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  
    }else{//else use first directory
        $target_file = $target_dir . $ref . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "1" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, mkdir($mypath,0777,TRUE); did mean that now when the suer tries the first time it creates the correct path and puts the file/s there. however now if the user trys to uplaod a second time with the same reference, it creates the folder (2) but doesnt input the file there.

The error i get is:
arning: move_uploaded_file(docs/123452/2.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\test\upload.php on line 32

and

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php736D.tmp' to 'docs/123452/2.png' in C:\wamp\www\test\upload.php on line 32

Comment: Oh, there is a \ missing here before $new_folder: 
$target_file = $target_dir . $ref . $new_folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you a lot for this. All works good. I know people dont like threads on here asking for debugging essentually. But this has really helped me get to grips with how it works.

Comment: as an aside; Windows doesn't usually give a flying sausage whether you use \ or / normally - it's even quite happy with things like `./` - you can use `realpath()` though instead of a bazillion `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`s : http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Comment: @CD001: I didn't know that slashes are valid under windows, thanks for the correction